# Debugging a rather difficult/complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having troubles in making a rather difficult MySQL query work. I've been trying, but creating complex queries has never been my strong side.

This query includes 4 tables, which I'll describe of course.

First, we have **`song`** table, which I need to select the needed info from.

```
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(6)    | NO   | PRI | -       | auto_increment |
| Anime        | char(100) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| Title        | char(100) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| Type         | char(20)  | NO   |     | -       |                |
| Singer       | char(50)  | NO   |     | -       |                |
| Youtube      | char(30)  | NO   |     | -       |                |
| Score        | double    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Ratings      | int(8)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Favourites   | int(7)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| comments     | int(11)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| release_year | int(4)    | NO   |     | 2019    |                |
| season       | char(10)  | NO   |     | Spring  |                |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then we have **`song_ratings`**, which basically represents the lists of each user, since once you rate a song, it appears on your list.

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | 0                 | auto_increment |
| UserID     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
| SongID     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
| Rating     | double   | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| RatedAt    | datetime | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| Favourited | int(1)   | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Users have the option to create custom lists(playlists), and this is the table which they are stored in. This is table `lists`.

```
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | 0                 | auto_increment |
| userID     | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
| name       | char(50)  | NO   |     | -                 |                |
| likes      | int(11)   | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| favourites | int(11)   | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| created_at | datetime  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| cover      | char(100) | NO   |     | -                 |                |
| locked     | int(1)    | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| private    | int(1)    | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

And finally, the table which contains all the songs that have been added to any playlists, called `list_elements`.

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       | auto_increment |
| listID | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| songID | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What my query needs to do is list all the songs that are on the list of a user, basically these are the record in `song_ratings` where the `userID` = ?(obviously the `ID` of the user), but are not on a specific playlist(has no record in `list_elements`) where the `ID`/`listID` = ?(the ID of that playlist).

This is the query I've been using so far, but after a while I had realized this doesn't actually work the way I wanted to.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    song
INNER JOIN song_ratings ON song_ratings.songID = song.ID
LEFT JOIN list_elements ON song_ratings.songID = list_elements.songID
WHERE
    song_ratings.userID = 34 AND list_elements.songID IS NULL
```

I have also tried something like this, and several variants of it

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   COUNT(*)
FROM
    song
INNER JOIN song_ratings ON song_ratings.songID = song.ID

INNER JOIN lists ON lists.userID = song_ratings.userID

LEFT JOIN list_elements ON song_ratings.songID = list_elements.songID

WHERE
    song_ratings.userID = 34 AND lists.ID = 1
```

To make it easier, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed8073), with all the necessary tables and records in them.

What you need to know. When you check for the playlist with the `ID` of **1**, the query needs to return **23**(basically all matches).

When you do the same with the `ID` **4**, it need to return **21**, if the query works correctly, because the playlist 1 is empty, thus all of the songs in the table `song_ratings` can be added to it(at least the ones that exist in `song` table, which is only half of the overall records now).

But playlist **4** already has 2 songs added to it, so only 21 are left available for adding.

Or in case the number are wrong, **playlist 1** needs to return all matches. **playlist 4** need to return all matches-2(because 2 songs are already added).

The `userID` needs to remain the same(34), and there are no records with different ID, so don't change it.

Comment: `I hope I managed to explain it properly` I would suggest you failed in that endeavour, but not to worry, just see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses in the INT() data type, is almost entirely meaningless.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer I get that, and know it, but I still don't prefer that style, because that way it just seems like I'm demanding an asnwer, which is technically true, but it'd still be a rather impolite way to do it in my opinion.

Comment: The [community has decided upon this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) already. See also the sidebar for related questions. We are firmly decided, at least for now, that succinct technical writing is preferred.

Comment: I came here trying to find a better way to debug 300+ line queries with multiple joins, unions and filtering. The title + finding the query in question was less than 10 lines made me chuckle :D (happy to see you found a good solution too) :D 
BTW if any of you reading that comment has some resource on that. Please DO leave me a link. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try subquery with NOT IN clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COUNT(*)
FROM
song
INNER JOIN song_ratings ON song_ratings.songID = song.ID
WHERE
song_ratings.userID = 34 AND song.ID not in (select songID from list_elements group by songID)
```

Comment: With checking the `listID`, by adding `WHERE listID=?` it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your original query was almost correct. When you use a column from a  joined table with a LEFT JOIN in the WHERE-clause, it causes the LEFT JOIN to turn into an INNER JOIN.

You can put the condition into the `ON`-clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM song
  INNER JOIN song_ratings ON song_ratings.songID = song.ID
  LEFT JOIN list_elements ON song_ratings.songID = list_elements.songID 
                             AND list_elements.songID IS NULL
WHERE song_ratings.userID = 34
```

Using JOINs in MySQL is faster than using subqueries, this would probably be faster as well.

Btw, you do not need `DISTINCT` when you only have `COUNT(*)`. The `COUNT(*)` returns only one row so there is no need to take distinct values from one value.